# Translation error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSString *soundURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=%@&tl=%@",strTextOfFilter,strCodeOfLanguage];
        NSLog(@"URL : %@",soundURL);
```

this show:`http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD&tl=zh-TW`

copy url to Browser of firefox. it's right  Translation of Chinese,but to Browser of safari ,it's error!    why Translation Chinese is error. others language is right!!
please help me !!!

```
    NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:soundURL]];
    NSLog(@"returnSoundData:%@",[NSURL URLWithString:soundURL]);
    NSError *err = nil;
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundData error: &err];
    [player play];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put `&ie=UTF-8` explicitly at the end of the URL, both in Safari and in your code.

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD&tl=zh-TW&ie=UTF-8
```

does the job. I guess the Google server was confused by the encoding used.